# space out elements in an inline block

Tags: html, css

I don't want the icons in an inline block to be touching, I want to space them out. To do that, I wanted to add a container around each block, then center the icons in the containers and have the containers in the block.

https://jsfiddle.net/mfw3ntnm/

```
.foot-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-holder {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  align-content: center;
}
```

When I run it without the image-holder it displays as an inline block, but the formatting is lost when I add the second class. How can I get the images to be wrapped by and centered in a container without losing the inline-block formatting?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/mfw3ntnm/1/

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you draw a picture of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yup, you got it Niles. So I just had to have the inline-block part in the image-holder class. That all makes sense now actually, thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just use margins?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to think about it.
https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/1t6er3m0/

```
<ul class='thing-list'>
  <li class='thing'>
    thing 1
  </li>
  <li class='thing'>
    thing 2
  </li>
  <li class='thing'>
    thing 3
  </li>
</ul>
```

...

```
.thing-list {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center; /* for inline and inline-block child elements */
}

.thing-list .thing {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block; /* allows it to be centered by parent rule */
}

.thing-list .thing:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: 1rem; /* one way to space them out */
  /* you could also use padding - or flexbox */
}
```

If they are touch icons... I would recommend going with padding so there is a larger touch area. I'll add that to the fiddle. : )

```
<ul class='icon-list'>
  <li class='icon'>
    <a href='#'>I1</a>
  </li>
  <li class='icon'>
    <a href='#'>I2</a>
  </li>
  <li class='icon'>
    <a href='#'>I3</a>
  </li>
  <li class='icon'>
    <a href='#'>I4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

...

```
.icon-list {
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-list .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-list .icon a {
  display: block; /* so it has solid area to touch */
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.icon-list .icon a:hover {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put a margin on only the 2nd image container(margin-left and right). See sample below

```css
.foot-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
}
.image-holder {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.image-holder:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
/**if more than 3 images
.image-holder:nth-child(even) {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
**/
```

```html
<div class="foot-bar">
  <div class="image-holder">
    <a href="about.html">
      <img src="images/profile.png" width="100" height="100" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="image-holder">
    <a href="projects.html">
      <img src="images/projects.png" width="100" height="100" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="image-holder">
    <a href="blogs.html">
      <img src="images/blogs.png" width="100" height="100" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```